# Airflow run bash command on an existing docker container

Tags: docker, airflow

I have Airflow running in a Docker container and I want to trigger a python script that resides in another container.  I tried the regular bash operator but that seems to be only for local.  Also looked at the Docker operator but that one seems to want to create a new container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The airflow container must be able to access the python script to be executed. If the script is in another container, either you mount a volume that airflow can access it or you can execute DAG with KubernetesPodOperator.